# Google-Maps error in IE7-IE8 in main.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-7

On my website ( http://goo.gl/j4EJn ), i'm building a Google Maps block, and with ajax-calls I render a route on the Google Maps. For each route i use an ajax-call (with jQuery) and some maps contain 20 routes.  Everything works perfect in FF, Chrome, IE9.  Since a few days, i receive complaints about the  routes not working in IE7 and IE8.

The routes did work before, it was fully tested on all IE7, IE8 and IE9 but now i get a javascript error: SCRIPT16389: unspecified error, main.js, line 37 character 2399.  The main.js referes to http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/nl_nl/mapfiles/api-3/8/2/main.js.

The jQuery class I wrote contains a try {..} catch(err){} syntax in every function so when an error would ocure in my class, it would trigger it.

All the ajax-calls are executed in IE7 and IE8.  I even tried to set the async-property of jQuery to true.  After changing the property, I discovered the randomness of the error.  Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't..

Anoyone got an idea what the problem could be?

Thx in advance.

Comment: It's highly probable that the issue isn't with browser comapatability and that it's with syntax errors in your script such a trailing comma - trailing commas = bane of IE

Comment: The error occurs inside the google-API, it would be more helpful for debugging when you log the calls of the API-methods and the passed arguments to isolate the issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a trailing comma.. Had that error before en those occure every time.  This error  comes up randomly (on the same page, after refreshing the page).

Comment: The problem happens when creating a map (var objMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(strMap), $arrMapOptions);)
I've even put a try-catch around it but still the error pops up.